# in R desolve SIR model with loop and if else

Tags: r, parameters, ode, desolve

I have a simple SIR model, I am trying to implement a vaccination approach (V) where at first it is checked if the infected are higher than a threshold (100), and if there are still enough susceptibles left (50) it will vaccinate a certain number per timestep (50).

However what I am trying to do, is that once the condition is fulfilled it should vaccinate for 7 days (regardless of whether during these 7 days the infected are still higher than the threshold or not, for example if after day 4,  **I = 70** it should still continue, it should only stop if S < 50. After the 7 days are finished, it should check the condition again, and either start again for another 7 days or not.

What I have so far,
I would be grateful if someone helped me implement that loop

```
sirV=function(time, y, params){

S    = y[1]
I    = y[2]
R    = y[3]
V   = y[4]

 with(as.list(params),{
 vac_helper = if (I > 100 & S > 50) {50}

 else {0}
 N = S+I+R+V
 dS = -S*beta*I/N  - vac_helper
 dI = S*beta*I/N - gamma*I
 dR = +gamma*I
 dV = vac_helper

 return(list(c(dS, dI, dR, dV)))
})
}


 myparameters = c(gamma=1/10,beta=0.2)
 times <- seq(0, 300)
 my_ode <- as.data.frame(ode( y=c(100000, 10, 0,0), times, sirV, myparameters))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, but I am not entirely sure it behaves the way you wanted to, so please check it first and come back to me if it doesn't.
Note that `end` has to be in the global environment.

```r
library(deSolve)

sirV = function(time, y, params){
  
  S    = y[1]
  I    = y[2]
  R    = y[3]
  V    = y[4]
  
  with(as.list(params),{
    
    # Has the previous vaccination ended, and do we still need to vaccinate?
    if(time > end & I > 100) {
      end <<- time + 7
    }
    
    # Can we vaccinate?
    vaccinate = ifelse(end > time & S > 50, 50, 0)
    
    N = S+I+R+V
    dS = -S*beta*I/N  - vaccinate
    dI = S*beta*I/N - gamma*I
    dR = gamma*I
    dV = vaccinate
    
    # Store some results in a global list so we can check what is happening under the hood
    temp = data.frame(time, end, S, I, R, V, dS, dI, dR, dV, vaccinate)
    catch_results[[length(catch_results)+1]] <<- temp

    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR, dV)))
  })
}

myparameters = c(gamma = 1/10, beta = 0.2)
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 300, by = 1)


end <- 0 # Reset end time
catch_results = list() # Catch results from inside the function
my_ode <- ode( y=c(100000, 10, 0, 0), times, sirV, myparameters)

plot(my_ode)
```

[image]

```r
# Check this to see if we get the expected behavior, especially at around time = 189
results = dplyr::bind_rows(catch_results)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>